# AlertDialog textinput sets time for timer. Format must be 00:00:00 but user can still put any number, which causes error. How do I limit the input?

Tags: java, android, input, timer, string-formatting

Hello fellow hardworking friends!

I have a timer in my app that works perfectly.
The user input for the time is from an alert dialog:

```
private void showChangeTimerDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Change Timer");

        final EditText timeInput = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        timeInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME);
        timeInput.setHint("Must be in 00:00:00 format");
        builder.setView(timeInput);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                TimePreference timePreference = new TimePreference(MainActivity.this);
                timePreference.setTime(timeInput.getText().toString());

                String newTimer = timePreference.getTime();
                timerText.setText(newTimer);
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

In order for the timer to work the user MUST input exactly in the format 00:00:00 for the app to work, for example 00:10:00 for 10 minutes.

Currently the user can still input a random number such as 10, which will feed into the TextView of the timer as just 10 and when the user presses the Start button for the timer the app crashes with `"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2".`

**My question is:
How do I limit the User input in the alert dialog to be strictly in 00:00:00 format, so that when for example the user inputs 10 it appears as 10:00:00 or 00:00:10.**

Thank you for the help!

Please let me know if you need any other part of my code.

For Reference, below is my code for the timer (the start button part):

```
startTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String strInput = timerText.getText().toString();

                startTime.setEnabled(false);
                toggleBtn.setEnabled(true);
                resetTime.setEnabled(true);

                isPaused = false;
                isCanceled = false;


                String[] tokens = strInput.split(":");
                int secondsToMs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) * 1000;
                int minutesToMs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) * 60000;
                int hoursToMs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) * 3600000;
                final long millisInFuture = secondsToMs + minutesToMs + hoursToMs;
                long countDownInterval = 1000;


                new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if (isCanceled || isPaused) {
                            cancel();
                        } else {
                            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                            final String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                            timerText.setText(hms);
                            remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        timerText.setText("00:00:00");

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addTextChangedListener` and in `onTextChanged` add ":" after every two chars the user is typing.
Or put three Texview Instead of one and limit the number of chars in each one, to two. in the end, combine all the three Strings to one in the format you want

And just to be curious, why not use timePicker?

Comment: I didn't use timePicker because I didn't know about it! :) I am rather new to programming and I learn something new everyday. For this case I believe I need a custom number picker, and I can use some help with the code tailored to my original problem, can you help?

Comment: I guess I will accept the answer as I used the timePicker and it worked after hours of work! :)

Comment: you can take the time from the timePicker and format it to any stringFotmat you want. It's very eazy to use...